# How to create a metric based on the data from the previous date?

Tags: gooddata

I'm trying to create insight in that way, that it is always based on the previous day's data. How can I create a metric in that way that the user's choice of the data range in the dashboard wouldn't have any influence on the visualization? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can write your metrics to select the previous day’s data and then ignore the parent filters coming from the report or dashboard with WITHOUT PF statement. You can achieve it by MAQL below:

`SELECT COUNT Event WHERE <date_attribute> = THIS - 1 WITHOUT PF`